# How to find point on a line segment?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find the point $1/3$ of the way down the line from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$. I thought using the formula $p(t) = x_1(1 - t) + x_2(t)$ would work, but I get the wrong values. Any help?

Comment: What value of $t$ did you use?

Comment: Your formula works, if interpreted correctly.  If the point you seek is $(x,y)$, then $x=x_1(1-t)+x_2(t)$ and $y=y_1(1-t)+y_2(t)$, where $t=1/3$.  John's answer illustrates this with vectors.

Comment: Hmm. I guess it was a programming error then. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The vector from $(x_1, y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$ is $\vec{d} = (x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1)$.

So start at the first point and add $\frac{1}{3}\vec{d}$:  $(x_1 + \frac{1}{3}(x_2-x_1), y_1 + \frac{1}{3}(y_2 - y_1))$.